# Where I can find google ads refresh token

Tags: django, google-ads-api

I would like call google ads API with django application and I am unable to find refresh_token

I am using below code

credentials = {
    'developer_token': 'xxxx',
    'refresh_token': '',
    'client_id': 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'client_secret': 'xxx'}

```
adwords_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_dict(credentials)
```

And getting below code in django

('invalid_request: Missing required parameter: refresh_token', '{\n  "error": "invalid_request",\n  "error_description": "Missing required parameter: refresh_token"\n}')

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the initial authentication script provided by Google first. [You can get it here.](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/master/examples/authentication/authenticate_in_standalone_application.py)

Download that and run it from the command line and it will open a browser window for you displaying a code. Copy the code and paste it back into the command line. Google will then do the dance and provide you with a refresh token on the command line. Copy and paste this into your google_ads.yaml file. It doesn't expire, so it only needs to be done once.